# Java WebDriver: How can I obtain an instance of a Coordinates class?

Tags: java, mouse, webdriver, coordinates, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate a GWT web app and standard clicks on a button don't work.
Therefore, I am simulating mouse events instead.
The code examples found online:

```
Mouse mouse = ((HasInputDevices)driver).getMouse();
mouse.mouseDown((Coordinates)myButton.getLocation());
mouse.mouseUp((Coordinates)myButton.getLocation());
```

But then I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Point cannot be cast to Coordinates
```

How can I obtain a valid instance of a Coordinates object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it..

```
Locatable button = (Locatable) myButton;
Mouse mouse = ((HasInputDevices)driver).getMouse();
mouse.mouseDown(button.getCoordinates());
mouse.mouseUp(button.getCoordinates());
```